# Exclude table columns while exporting it into Excel in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, typescript, react-table

I have to export my HTML table into Excel sheets. I researched a lot and found a solution. It works for me but the problem is, there is some image field in my table data and I want to remove it from table export (suppose the first column). How can I modify my code to get the desired result?

```js
downloadVenues = () => {
  var downloadLink;
  var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
  var tableSelect = document.getElementById("venue-table");
  var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

  // Specify file name
  var filename = 'venues_data.xls';

  // Create download link element
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
      type: dataType
    });
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have this question as well, with the exact same code. Did you sort it out?

Comment: Yes, I sorted it out.instead of exporting data from tables, I exported it from API data itself.

Comment: I did sort this out, will post an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to remove all the td, tr, th or anything else with a class or id before exporting to Excel.

Set the class .remove-this to any th and td you want to remove.

```
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){

var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var cloneTable = table.cloneNode(true);
jQuery(cloneTable).find('.remove-this').remove();

var downloadLink;
var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
var tableSelect = cloneTable;
var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

// Specify file name
filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

// Create download link element
downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
        type: dataType
    });
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
}else{
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    
    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

}

Original code: https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/